using postgreSQL table to plot geometry in dash leaflet
I have multiple shape files which are publicly available for UK region.
i have loaded these shape files to postgreSQL using postGIS and the geometry (with multipolygons) of the shapes are captured.
now im pulling these tables from postGIS to Dash using the query
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(query, connection)
the type of my output df is geodataframe
however im not able to convert this data into a geojson to plot it on dash leaflet map
this is the structure of my table pulled from postgres to dash
the data is normalized table
i want a generic solution to convert all tables to geojsons so its applicable for other shape files too
pandas-geojson module is not supported in my current dash environment

resolved my issue the polygons coordinates are in meters and leaftlet is not supporting. so once i convert to lat longs it worked

Cool! If you want to resolve your question so it doesn't stay open that'll be great :)
